# Given..When..Then User Story examples for REST APIs

Tags: rest, github, gherkin

Do agile people use this kind of style to develop APIs?

Are there any decent examples?

The examples that I found on the internet so far are minimal (same applies for ch. 12 of "The Cucumber book"). I checked for .feature files with the word "Given" in github, the results are too many and all of them irrelevant to my use case. Can I search in a more sophisticated way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I'm not sure if defining pre- and post-condition to a RESTful API are that useful. REST defines its possible operations through the underlying protocol. Most often this is HTTP (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, ...) on some negotiable representation formats (plain/text, text/html, application/json, application/xml, ...). A well-developed content type may also support RESTful clients with performing further actions (i.e. HAL, ATOM, ...) and thus make given-when-then documentation redundant.

Comment: @Roman Vottner I don't understand the point you make, gherkin will be used to develop the API in a BDD manner. Acceptance tests will be written in the sense of "given conditions, when client does this, then the response should be that". Isn't this a friendly way to develop?

Edit: Is it because I wrote "describe APIs" instead of "develop APIs"? If so I meant develop.

Comment: So, the actual question is more related towards testing rather then productive code? If so, I misunderstood your actual question. I thought you were asking for some WADL, Swagger, ... alternatives (which I'm not a big fan of as they contradict the basic REST philosophy) to automatically instrument REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as if you are looking for complicated examples to be able to claim that this is the way to do it.

From my perspective, the examples in ch 12 of the Cucumber book may seem trivial. But I think they may be too technical. I am not sure a product owner, or similar non technical person, will be able to validate them.

My point here is that the scenarios should be as non technical as possible and therefore contain a minimum, if any, technical details. This will result in something a non technical person can verify. You will be able to discuss the solution of your business problem rather than technical details. Details that may or may not be important for the business. It is probably not even interesting at the level where BDD often operates to know if this is implemented using REST or if something else is used.

If it is testing you are looking for, other tooling may be more applicable and perhaps easier to use than any BDD tool. These tools may, however, not be easy to use a discussion basis when trying to understand the business problem that you ultimately will solve.

Comment: I am looking for thorough examples to see how it's done. If it's done at all that is.

I do agree that user stories should not be technical. My goal is not testing. Even TDD and BDD, although based on testing, are developing methods. But I don't necessarily want to do strict BDD, more like a new method to build APIs.